sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade just cleared/reset our config files
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade just cleared/reset our config files. Is this normal? This update/upgrade included new releases and upgrades for ROS2 Jazzy.
We were working with packages that are installed by apt install ros-jazzy-<package name> such as cartographer or twist-mux, and we've left those packages in their location:
/opt/ros/jazzy/share/<package name>/

We were changing some config files, like /config/twist_mux_topics.yaml and params.
After sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, all our custom config params were cleared and reset to a new installation with default values.
Needless to say, we will be making backup files for our config/yaml/lua files from now on. But should we instead copy packages into our workspaces, i.e. ~/ros2_ws/src/?
I wonder what are best practices here and if this could happen again/frequently.
Best,
N

Keeping the ros 2 installation clean is the best practice, you should never add your packages to it or modify it. It is technically doable but it only adds up and when you apt upgrade your os you don't know what can breaks. To keep your workspace isolated ros2_ws you can distribute it in the future move it around without needing to worry. So my recommendation is to compile you workspace with config files inside and source it then run any executable you have, while keeping the ros 2 installation clean. You can refer to the ros 2 documentation on how to distribute your package or multiple packages.

You can leave the packages themselves in the ros install directory. Best practice is instead to create your own package in ~/ros2_ws/src/, something like ~/ros2_ws/src/your_package_name, and place the config files in there, then either using a command line argument or a custom launch file to launch the installed nodes, direct the node to use your custom launch file.
For example, instead of ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py, you can do ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py params_file:=<full/path/to/config/nav2_params.yaml>
If you look into the documentation for your packages, they should give you the correct arguments for this. Alternatively, and easier for long term development, creating a custom launch file in your dev node, which is a copy of the one you are calling from the node, and customize it to your needs.
